# Spliting long commands to increase speed in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have 2 functions, that calculates the root of function `ax^2+bx+c` with smaller absolute value (`a`,`b`,`c`,`x` are vectors):

```
function x = minroot(a,b,c)
% f1
d = sqrt(b.*b-4*a.*c);
x = (-2*c)./(b+sign(b).*d);
```

and:

```
function x = minroot(a,b,c)
% f2
x = (-2*c)./(b+sign(b).*sqrt(b.*b-4*a.*c));
```

As you can see, the only difference between them is that in `f1` the variable `d` is calculated separately.

To my surprise I have noticed that `f1` works consistently faster (around 5% faster).

Can you tell me why `f1` is working faster and when should I split my commands to make the program faster?

---

Test code:

```matlab
function t = test()
a = rand(10000000,1);
b = rand(10000000,1);
c = rand(10000000,1);

x = minroot1(a,b,c);
y = minroot2(a,b,c);
assert(all(abs(x-y)./abs(x) < 1e-9))

t1 = timeit(@()minroot1(a,b,c));
t2 = timeit(@()minroot2(a,b,c));

t = t2/t1;
end

function x = minroot1(a,b,c)
d = sqrt(b.*b-4*a.*c);
x = (-2*c)./(b+sign(b).*d);
end

function x = minroot2(a,b,c)
x = (-2*c)./(b+sign(b).*sqrt(b.*b-4*a.*c));
end
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you bench-marked those two.

Comment: @SardarUsama done.

Comment: Please show the executable code you used to bench-mark it. Please show how are you calculating those times. Are you calculating time manually?

Comment: @SardarUsama unfortunately I don't have the source code, I have only precompiled code. All the information I have, I have put in the question

Comment: So? Benchmark it again. You are making a claim, support it with evidence ([mre])

Comment: "I don't have the source code, I have only precompiled code" How is this possible? You've written a test to time the computations, compiled it (how?) and thrown away the sources? That doesn't make any sense! In any case, it takes half a minute to write such a test.

Comment: Using the test code added, I always get that `minroot2` is faster.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Yes, the larger the array, the better the benefit of `minroot2`. For very small arrays it seems that `minroot1` is a bit faster, this could be because the 2nd one has a more complex JITted code, and there is less benefit to avoiding the intermediate matrix. But for very small sizes, the function is so fast that a small benefit one way or the other is hardly noticeable.

Comment: @CrisLuengo 
@AnderBiguri 1. The testing function was not mine, that's why I had only precompiled version. 2. After adding two zeros to the size of `a`, `b`, `c` (I said earlier, that designated size of parematers are few millions at least), then first function is, as I said, faster.

Comment: I have edited your testing function, according to my previous comment. You can check it again now

Comment: I see the 1-line version being consistently 15% faster for arrays of size 1e7 (MATLAB R2017a). What's your version of MATLAB?

Comment: @CrisLuengo R2019b

Comment: @CrisLuengo for me the ratio t2/t1 is consistently above 1.05

Comment: Maybe submit a bug report to MATLAB. The JIT is supposed to be able to optimize the one-liner better.

Comment: I am using R2019b and the ratio is below 1 (about 10-25%)

Comment: @max how is it possible?